# How send URL as response whenever user send post value in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Guys i want to return a URL of HTML page as response , when ever user send value by post method

Actually the HTML page will contains data posted by user,

But what actually happening is when user post data it opening that HTML page ,

code i tried

```
class CoordView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Coord.objects.all()
renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)
serializer_class = CoordSerializer
template_name = 'index.html'
id = {'id':id }
Response ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/{{id}}')
```

But I want to return that HTML page URL to user.

Comment: You're already in the view of that URL, aren't you? You can get the current URL with `self.request.path` from `post`/`create` method of the viewset.

Comment: Hi can you please mention a code here , i am new to django. @heemayl